# Open APK programmatically with Xamarin Forms - Android 8.1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to install an APK from my Xamarin.Forms application.
I've created a DependencyService in Android implementation using FileProvider with this piece of code:

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(updtFile);
var realUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(MainActivity.Instance, MainActivity.Instance.PackageName + ".provider", file);
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
install.SetDataAndType(realUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(install);
```

It works flawlessly with Android 7, opening the package manager as expected.
It does absolutely nothing with Android 8.1, not even throwing an exception or so. I have all permission enabled for the app and if I try to open the APK with file explorer it works without any problem.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.1.0" package="..." android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="..." android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>
```

And this is provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I was missing this permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```